# rails routes set request header in routing tests using routing assertions

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5, rails-routing

Wrote a test using the routing assertions helper, where I want to set the request header to Facebook Share bot

```
class RoutesTest < ActionController::TestCase

    test 'route social share bot to bots controller' do
            assert_recognizes({controller: 'bots', action: 'index'}, '/careers/1', 
                { @request.headers['HTTP_USER_AGENT'] => 'facebookexternalhit/1.1 (+http://www.facebook.com/externalhit_uatext.php)' })
    end
end
```

The test logs the actual recognized options shows up as

```
{
 "controller"=>"site/pages", 
 "action"=>"home", "path"=>"careers/1", 
 "Rails Testing"=>"facebookexternalhit/1.1 (+http://www.facebook.com/externalhit_uatext.php)"
}
```

This doesn't look to me as if it has set the request headers. A bit confused on whether I am setting the user agent header correctly here or not?

***Update***

Going by ActionContoller::TestCase documentation, this should have worked

```
test 'route social share bot to bots controller' do
        @request.user_agent = 'facebookexternalhit/1.1 (+http://www.facebook.com/externalhit_uatext.php)'
        assert_recognizes({controller: 'site/bots', action: 'index', path: 'careers/1'}, '/careers/1')
end
```

but that doesn't set the user agent either, I've also tried the `@request.env['HTTP_USER_AGENT']` flavour

Comment: What you did at the end?

Comment: Sorry I don't have that code handy with me now, and it's been too long so my memory fails me as well.